# tkinter run in CMD on Windows 10

Tags: python, tkinter

My tkinter code doesnt launch(stay in display when i run from cmd line (F:\PYTHON\tkinterwork>tester.py)

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
#Step 1: Crate Label Widget#
myLabel1 = Label(root, text="Hello World")
myLabel2 = Label(root, text="It's going to Rain Today")
myLabel1.grid(row=0, column = 0)
myLabel2.grid(row=1, column = 0)
##put it on to the screen
#myLabel.pack()
## Event loop
root.mainloop()
```

A black screen appears then vanishes. It works fine in Spyder IDE

Comment: The command in the command line should be `py "F:\PYTHON\tkinterwork\tester.py"`.

Comment: that is the directory im am just calling tester.py

Comment: Ok, then the command should be `py tester.py`.

Comment: No, its in enviorment variables

Comment: You mean PATH? Ok, that just means you could use `python tester.py` as well.

Comment: If you have associated `.py` to correct Python executable, your code should work fine.